# In a N x M matrix find the max number of neighbours equal to the number they are neighbouring in optimal time

Tags: algorithm, performance, search

If you are wondering no, this is not my homework it's just am execise that I found online and couldn't get my head around it.

You are given an N x M matrix only with ones and zeroes in it. . A neighbour can by a number up, down, left, down or on the diagonal. Most numbers have 8 neighbours while those on the side have 5 and those on each of the four corners have 3. I have to find the max number of neighbours that are equal to a number in the matrix.

The problem is that I don't know how to do it without checking every number in the matrix (N x M checkings).

Comment: Well, if "you have to check for *every number*" you have to check (in the worst case) the entire board, i.e. **N x M** checkings

Comment: The problem didn't actually say that you have to check every number, it only said to do it in optimal time

Comment: I will edit that out

Comment: Why is "I don't know how to do it without checking every number" a problem?

Comment: Because I simply don't know the idea behind doing so.

Comment: Do you really think that there is a better way than N X M checking because it is already linear time?

Comment: I tought that because the said exercise told me to do it in optimal time since there isn't a slower aproapch than a linear one.

Comment: I do not think any better way than linear because you have to iterate through all the elements at least once to really know about neighbors. However you can optimize your linear algorithm if that make any difference to the overall timing.

Comment: @user7416538 You repeatedly say that "the exercise says to do it in optimal time", and that this is your reason for presuming there is something better than linear time; but that quote does not say anything about whether linear time is optimal or not. You have attempted to prove that linear time is not optimal by finding something sublinear and failing; now I propose that you try to prove that linear time *is* optimal and see if you can make that proof go through. If so, you're done; if not, that should guide you on your next sublinear attempt -- or at least make for a better SO question.

Comment: Add a concrete example. Like a 3 by 3 matrix. Expected input and output. The problem is a little bit vague.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot avoid checking every element of the matrix.

Think of a "checkerboard" matrix:

```
1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0
0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1
1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0
0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1
1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0
0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1
1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0
0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1
```

Ignoring the edges for the time being, every element has four equal neighbors. But if you negate any one element (turning a 0 to a 1 or a 1 to a 0), some position will have five equal neighbors. So if you come up with an algorithm that never looks at the element at row r and column c when processing the checkerboard matrix, then you will certainly get the wrong answer for one of these two possible matrices: the checkerboard matrix above, and the checkerboard that has position (r,c) negated.